# React Router - Route does not load on navigation but does on direct link

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this set-up for routing on a component called Challenges like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <Route
      exact
      path={`${this.props.match.path}/:id`}
      render={() => (
        <P5Wrapper
          p5Props={{ controls: this.state.controls }}
          onSetAppState={this.onSetAppState}
        />
      )}
    />
  )
}

export default withRouter(connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Challenges));
```

And it's accessed by a NavLink in another component called Menu.js:

```
<NavLink to={`/${this.props.path}${item.link}`} key={item.text}>
  <ListItem button>
    <ListItemText primary={item.text} />
  </ListItem>
</NavLink>
```

Where this.props.path is set up to be *challenges* and the item.link is */1* (that could be any other number).

The problem is that when the page loads at */challenges* the menu and everything else is working correctly but when I click on the NavLink and the url changes to */challenges/1* the component P5Wrapper is not mounting on the page.

But if I access directly to */challenges/1* from the browser then it does mount the component and NavLinks for other item.link work correctly [i.e /challenges/5].

Here is an example of how the routing is not sending parameters to the component [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/756rp0qp0), am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are your `NavLink` and `Route` components wrapped inside one and the same `BrowserRouter`?

Comment: @Tholle Yes, they are both on the app component which is wrapped by the BrowserRouter.

Comment: @Tholle, I also added a `NavLink` to the Challenges component and does not work either.

Comment: That's frustrating. Consider creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) and it will be easier for someone to help.

Comment: @Tholle [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/756rp0qp0). Here I have an example, when clicking the navlink the challenges component does not recognizes the params sent.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what you mean. Your example seems to work great for me. When clicking the links, the rendered `id` switches between `1` and `2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap the order of your HOCs at the bottom.

So, it'd be:

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(withRouter(Challenges));
```